# Calling a method from a class in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi there best members,

i've a question about calling a method from my class into the UITableViewController, in this method called: loadData i've made connection to my localhost and getting a json object, the implementation of this method works so don't need to worry about that and when i NSLog it gives me the correct output.

The strange thing is when i'm calling this method into my ViewDidLoad method in my TableViewController i don't get anything back, how is this possible? Because when i'm move my method into the .h file of TableViewController and implement it to my TableViewController.m then it works.

Here an example.

```
@interface CLub : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *teams;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *teamName;
-(void)loadData;

@end

@implementation CLub

-(void)loadData {

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost/xampp/flashbackapi/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        self.club.teams = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.club.teams = [responseObject objectForKey:@"clubs"];




    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@",error,error.userInfo);
    }];



    [operation start];

}

@end

@implementation ClubsTableViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.club = [[CLub alloc]init];
    [self.club loadData];

}
```

I would be very greatfull if there is someone who can help me out or give me a good direction.

Comment: Show actual code (this looks like a part example which won't compile) and the test code. In what way doesn't it work (when do you check the result)?

Comment: It doesn't load the data into the UITableViewController.

Comment: It's asynchronous. When do you try to use it?

Comment: I have almost the same case, where I need to get data back from some communication object. I did it with NSNotification. At the other way I see some stuff, that I will do at the different way. id club = [[Club alloc]init]; ( also need an Init-method with self = [super init]); then [club loadData]; But what is the way to return data? Would you like to look inside the instance var? I would prefer NSNotification. There is no need to refresh or so.

Comment: i know it is asynchronous in the viewDidLoad of the ClubsTableViewController (check the code) but probably it shouldn't be there?

Comment: @Watsche aah thats probably the point.. i don't ininitialize the super class.. in the TableController. But there is no return type of loadData but in your scenario i've to give a return. In that case the return would be a NSArray. But why do you use id Club... ? you know club is an instance of class Club why should u give that an id?

Comment: Not sure about other way, because I'am doing this like in the book. The init-method return self and this is the id type. The id is the pointer to your instance, so you can work with it. If you will call your data from the instance array, there is a problem. It could be empty, because the array will be called before the data was pushed there. You need to call more times, to watch if something has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @interface CLub : NSObject
>
> @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *teams;
>
> @property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *teamName;
>
> -(void)loadData;
>
> @end
>
> @implementation CLub
>
> -(id)init{
>
> ```
> self = [super init];
> if (self) {
>  teams = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
>
> }
> return self;
> ```
>
> }
>
> -(BOOL)loadData {
>       BOOL isDataLoaded = NO;
>       NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@""];
>       NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    self.club.teams = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.club.teams = [responseObject objectForKey:@"clubs"];

    isDataLoaded = YES;
    return isDataLoaded ;



} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error %@ %@",error,error.userInfo);
    isDataLoaded = NO;
    return isDataLoaded ;

}];

[operation start];
return isDataLoaded;
```

> }
>
> @end

In the viewController check if returns yes

> @implementation ClubsTableViewController
>
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>
>   self.club = [[CLub alloc]init]; 
>     BOOL isDataLoadedSuccessFully=    [self.club loadData];
>
> if(isDataLoadedSuccessFully){ 
>   //Reload UI
>   }else{}
>
> }

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank u sooo much i'm gonna test this out, as i look trought the code i is clear to me.